# C# mvc saving deviceconfig as new config id in foreign table

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq, entity-framework-6

I am trying to create a system where it is possible to add/ change device configurations. The user should be able to add / delete rows at the same time.
Everytime a config is saved, a new config_id is created and VersionNr is increased.

I am 100% sure I am doing something wrong, and what is going wrong. But I dont know how to fix it or improve it.

Here is my code:

```
public ActionResult Edit(int? Id)
        {
            //create new list
            var Device_Pricelist = new List<Device_Pricelist>(db.Device_Pricelist.Where(r => r.DeviceConfig.Device_config_id == Id));

        //create new SelectList in Device_Pricelist
        var SelectedCMI = (from d in db.pricelist
                           select new { d.Price_id, Value = d.bas_art_nr }).Distinct();

        //call viewbag based on SelectedCMI query
        ViewBag.SelectedCMI = new SelectList(SelectedCMI.Distinct(), "Price_id", "Value");

        return View(Device_Pricelist);
    }


 public ActionResult Edit([Bind(Include = "id,Device_config_id,Price_id,amount,assembly_order")]DeviceConfig deviceConfig, List<Device_Pricelist> device_Pricelists)
        {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            try
            {
                try
                {
                    db.DeviceConfig.Add(deviceConfig).Device_config_id = deviceConfig.Device_config_id++;
                    db.DeviceConfig.Add(deviceConfig).device_type_id = deviceConfig.device_type_id = 13;
                    db.DeviceConfig.Add(deviceConfig).Active = true;
                    //Needs to be based on current VersionNr in deviceConfig
                    db.DeviceConfig.Add(deviceConfig).VersionNr = deviceConfig.VersionNr + 1;
                    db.DeviceConfig.Add(deviceConfig).Date = deviceConfig.Date = DateTime.Now;
                }
                finally
                {

                    foreach (var item in device_Pricelists)
                    {

                        db.Entry(item).State = EntityState.Added;
                    }
                }

                db.SaveChanges();
                TempData["SuccesMessage"] = "Data is Succesfully saved";
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }
            catch
            {
                TempData["AlertMessage"] = "Saving Data Failed, " + "Try Again";
            }
        }
        return View(device_Pricelists);
    }
```

view:

```
@model List<ConcremoteDeviceManagment.Models.Device_Pricelist>

@{
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

@using (Html.BeginForm("Edit", "Home", FormMethod.Post))

{
    <h1>
        @Html.DisplayName("Edit Configuration")

    </h1>
    <h2>
      @*  @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.DeviceType.name)<br />*@dammit
    </h2>

    if (TempData["AlertMessage"] != null)
    {
        <p class="alert alert-danger" id="FailMessage">@TempData["AlertMessage"]</p>
    }
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    <div>
        @*  <a href="#" id="addNew" class="btn btn-primary">Add New</a>*@
    </div>
    <table class="table table-hover" id="dataTable">
        <tr>
            <th class="table-row">
                @Html.DisplayName("BAS artikelnummer")
            </th>
            <th class="table-row">
                @Html.DisplayName("Beschrijving")
            </th>
            <th class="table-row">
                @Html.DisplayName("Aantal")
            </th>
            <th class="table-row">
                @Html.DisplayName("Bouw Volgorde")
            </th>
            <th class="table-row">
                <a href="#" id="addNew" class="btn btn-success">Add New Row</a>
            </th>
        </tr>
        @if (Model != null && Model.Count > 0)
        {
            int j = 0;
            foreach (var item in Model)
            {
                <tr>
                    @Html.HiddenFor(a => a[j].id)
                    @Html.HiddenFor(a => a[j].Device_config_id)
@*                    @Html.HiddenFor(a => a[j].Price_id)*@

                    <td class="table-row">
                        @Html.DropDownListFor(a => a[j].Price_id, (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.SelectedCMI, null, new { @class = "form-control" })
                    </td>
                    <td class="table-row">
                            @Html.DisplayFor(a => a[j].Pricelist.description, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(a => a[j].Pricelist.description, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                        </td>
                    <td class="table-row">
                        @Html.EditorFor(a => a[j].amount, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(a => a[j].amount, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                    </td>
                    <td class="table-row">
                        @Html.EditorFor(a => a[j].assembly_order, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(a => a[j].assembly_order, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                    </td>
                    @*<td class="table-row">
                            @Html.DisplayFor(a => a[j].DeviceConfig.Date, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                        </td>*@
                    <td>
                        @if (j > 0)
                        {
                            <a href="#" id="remove" class="btn btn-danger">Remove</a>
                        }
                    </td>
                </tr>
                j++;
            }
        }
    </table>

    <input type="submit" value="Save Device Data" class="btn btn-primary" />
    <button onclick="location.href='@Url.Action("Index", "Home")';return false; " class="btn btn-primary">Back to list</button>

}
@section Scripts{
    @*@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")*@
    <script language="javascript">

        $(document).ready(function () {

            //1. Add new row
            $("#addNew").click(function (e) {
                e.preventDefault();

                var $tableBody = $("#dataTable");
                var $trLast = $tableBody.find("tr:last");
                var $trNew = $trLast.clone();

                var suffix = $trNew.find(':input:first').attr('name').match(/\j+/);
                $trNew.find("td:last").html('<a href="#" id="remove" class="btn btn-danger">Remove</a>');
                $.each($trNew.find(':input'), function (i, val) {
                    // Replaced Name
                    var oldN = $(this).attr('name');
                    var newN = oldN.replace('[' + suffix + ']', '[' + (parseInt(suffix) + 1) + ']', '[' + suffix + ']', '[' + (parseInt(suffix) + 1) + ']', '[' + suffix + ']', '[' + (parseInt(suffix) + 1) + ']');
                    $(this).attr('name', newN);
                    //Replaced value
                    var type = $(this).attr('type');
                    //if (type.toLowerCase() == "text") {
                    //    $(this).attr('value', '');
                    //}

                    // If you have another Type then replace with default value
                    $(this).removeClass("input-validation-error");

                });
                $trLast.after($trNew);

                // Re-assign Validation
                //var form = $("form")
                //    .removeData("validator")
                //    .removeData("unobtrusiveValidation");
                //$.validator.unobtrusive.parse(form);
            });

            // 2. Remove
            //$('a.remove').live("click", function (e) {   --> this is for old jquery library
            $('body').on("click", '#remove', function (e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                $(this).parent().parent().remove();
            });

        });
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function SelectedIndexChanged() {
            //Form post
            document.demoForm.submit();
        }
    </script>
```

I hope somebody is able to help me.
More information will be given when needed.

Comment: Srry, I added the wrong code, now correct code is added

Comment: You said what you want, but you didn't explain what to fix? What is the issue with current code and what do you expect it to do?

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya The current problem is that a new config id is created, but without the corresponding data(needs to be fixed) and the device_config data is added to the old config id. New versionNr isn't updated correctly aswell

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your method accepts 2 parameters but you are only posting 1 object - `List<Device_PriceList>`. Let's assume you want to construct a new DeviceConfig based on the existing one, you should change your Action method to the following:

```
public ActionResult Edit(List<Device_Pricelist> device_Pricelists)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        try
        {
            var deviceConfig = db.DeviceConfig.Find(device_Pricelists.First().Device_config_id);
            deviceConfig.device_type_id = 13;
            deviceConfig.Active = true;
            deviceConfig.VersionNr++;
            deviceConfig.Date = DateTime.Now;

            db.DeviceConfig.Add(deviceConfig);

            foreach(var item in device_Pricelists)
            {
                item.Device_config_id = deviceConfig.Device_config_id;
            }

            db.Device_Pricelists.AddRange(device_Pricelists);

            db.SaveChanges();
            TempData["SuccesMessage"] = "Data is Succesfully saved";
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
        catch
        {
            TempData["AlertMessage"] = "Saving Data Failed, Try Again";
        }
    }
    return View(device_Pricelists);
}
```

Remember when posting a list, you need to post complete sets of the object you're trying to map to. That is for example `[0].Id`, `[0].Device_config_id` (etc), `[1].Id`, `[1].Device_config_id` (etc).

Your JS doesn't seem correct, particularly the `.replace(..)` call with 6 parameters, so you're probably seeing lots of `[0]`s when you clone the rows. Some simpler JS that will get you the same result is:

```
var oldN = $(this).attr('name');
var idx = parseInt(oldN.substr(1, oldN.indexOf(']')));
var newN = oldN.replace('[' + idx + ']', '[' + (idx + 1) + ']');
```